# Как можно сделать поиск по названиям товаров WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

каким образом можно получить товары по названию? Я получаю все товары в категории, но мне нужен дополнительный фильтр по названии товара, как можно это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста

```
function get_vacancies_by_country($main_category="", $subcategory="england",$count_of_vacancies = 100){
    if($subcategory==''){
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 100,
            'tax_query'      => array( array(
                'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
                'field'      => 'slug',
                'terms'      => $main_category,
    ) ),
            'tax_query'      => array( array(
                'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
                'field'      => 'name',
                'terms'      => '',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ) )
          );
    }else{
        $args = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
            array(
             'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => $subcategory
            ),
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => $count_of_vacancies,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        );
    }
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    
    return $loop;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно добавить в аргумент ключ `title` если нужно 100% совпадение

если же нужно искать через like то тогда нужно использовать фильтр `posts_where`, например вот так

```
$args['_name_like'] = 'поисковый заголовок';

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

и через фильтр добавить условие

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'add_posts_title_where', 10, 2 );

function add_posts_title_where( $where, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post_title = $wp_query->get( '_name_like' );

    if ( $post_title ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( $wpdb->esc_like( $post_title ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    
    return $where;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно наложить дополнительный хук на post_where

```
function title_filter( $where, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $search_term = $wp_query->get( 'search_prod_title' ) ) {
        $where .= ' AND ' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE \'%' . esc_sql( like_escape( $search_term ) ) . '%\'';
    }
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'title_filter', 10, 2 );
```

в $args добавить дополнительный параметр, по которому будет поиск по названию

```
$args = array(
    //    
    'search_prod_title' => $search_prod_title
    //
);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, Ваш ответ тоже подходит, но жаль не могу оба выбрать как правильные)